# How does a value type holding a memory address for a reference type know to only hold the declared reference type?

Tags: c#, runtime, compile-time, reference-type

I'm doing some self-taught learning on how reference and value types are treated at compile-time and run-time. I was hoping I could get some input/feedback on my understanding of the following simple example.

```
class Animal
{
    string name;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Animal A; //Line 1
        A = new Animal(); //Line 2
    }
}
```

I understand that on Line 1 the compiler creates memory on the stack, i.e. A, to store a reference to an Animal instance (in the heap). On Line 2 an operation is performed by the runtime which creates an Animal instance (really just a string) and assigns its memory address to A. Please correct me if I'm wrong about anything here.

And I also understand that if I was simply assigning the number 5 to a declared int, this is fine since the compiler has created a memory layout capable of storing an int.

But for a reference type as shown above, from what I understand the compiler is creating a memory layout on the stack capable of storing a memory address, i.e. A, to an Animal instance on the heap.

I know we declared A as an Animal, but my question is, what is it about A that makes it only capable of storing a memory address of an Animal or a class instance derived from Animal?

Comment: "*what is it about A makes it only capable of storing a memory address*" - because it's a reference type which you decided when you used the `class` keyword, end of story

Comment: Also discussions about stack, heap, storage locations and memory layouts etc, are rarely useful out side of general academic interest for the CLI / runtime you are working with. They are implementation details, The ECMA CLI specs only gives minimal guarantees (if any) about these details. What is more important is the actual semantics of reference and value types.

Comment: _"What is it about A that makes it only capable of storing a memory address of an Animal"_ - type checking both within the compiler and at runtime.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. There must be some logic in the runtime that only permits an Animal instance (or its derivatives) being assigned to A? Is that part of the runtime's type checking?

Comment: That's an explicit guarantee of .net. A variable will *never* contain the wrong type. Unlike say the C language, which explicitly allows you to mix up types.

Comment: This is actually part of the Common Type System (CTS), which is enforced at compile time by the specs the compiler uses to convert to Common Intermediate Language (CIL), the Virtual Execution System (VES) and the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) are responsible for executing and implementing the CIL. To take a deep nasty dive into the internal workings of .net this is your friend https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/

Comment: Let's reverse the question: what is it about `A` that makes it capable of storing a memory address of *anything*? And wonce you have worked that out (from the specification), it should obvious that it can only contain instances of `A`, as that is how that location is defined